# Is is possible to concatenate the values of a field during the merging of records ?

Tags: apex, community

Is is possible to concatenate the values of a field during the merging of records ? 
 For example : BuyerConnection field on Record A1 = 'ca/phnx/nv'
                                        Record A2 = 'mo/oh/ny'

when these 2 records are merged I have to get the resultant field value on the winning record as 'ca/phnx/nv/mo/oh/ny'

any ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you using to merge these records? It's possible if you're building your own apex merge engine.

Comment: Hi @Bachovski.. I am using the standard merge stmt and donno how to customize it to implement this

Answer (score 2):

You can perform custom logic while merging using an after-delete trigger. Because the records are locked during the merge, you should use an asynchronous call (@future) to update the records afterwards. You can query the deleted records with the ALL ROWS keyword of SOQL.

Here's a demonstration:

Trigger:

```
trigger mergeAccount on Account (after delete) {
    AccountMerge.customMerge(Trigger.oldMap.keySet());
}
```

Class:

```
public class AccountMerge {
    @future
    public static void customMerge(Set<Id> accounts) {
        Map<Id, Account> oldAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name, Description, MasterRecordId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts ALL ROWS]);
        Map<Id, Account> newAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Account record:oldAccounts.values()) {
            newAccounts.put(record.MasterRecordId, null);
        }
        newAccounts.remove(null);
        if(newAccounts.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        newAccounts.putAll([SELECT Id, Description FROM Account WHERE Id IN :newAccounts.keySet() FOR UPDATE]);
        for(Id oldId: accounts) {
            Account oldAccount = oldAccounts.get(oldId), newAccount = newAccounts.get(oldAccount.MasterRecordId);
            if(String.isBlank(oldAccount.Description)) {
                continue;
            }
            if(String.isBlank(newAccount.Description)) {
                newAccount.Description = '';
            }
            newAccount.Description += '\n\nMerged from '+oldAccount.Name+':\n\n'+oldAccount.Description;
        }
        update newAccounts.values();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is standard functionality that will allow you to do that. I would suggest creating a custom Merge button and some VisualForce/Apex code to replicate the standard merge functionality with additional customised logic that will concatenate the values upon merging.

Comment: A trigger could merge fields based on custom logic; you can tell which record was merged into another by using the MasterRecordId field in the after-delete trigger.

Comment: @sfdcfox that is pretty sweet, seems like that'd be worthy of a separate answer on this question

Comment: I agree, didn't think of that :)

Comment: You all convinced me. Enjoy!